# Exportar el resultado de una consulta MySQL con PHP y jQUery

Tags: php, mysql, excel, exportar

les comento, en la aplicación que estoy haciendo, a una determinada hora del día la caja cierra y al cerrar ya no se puede generar más ventas por ese día, eso está cubierto, pero mi cliente quiere que al cerrar la caja, le llegue a su correo un archivo excel con los datos de las ventas de ese día.

Lo que pensé es, primero exporto los resultados a un archivo Excel y luego lo envío como archivo adjunto, pero mi problema está en exportar a Excel. Les muestro:

La parte del jQuery:

```
var urlAjaxExportExcel = base_url + "Ventas/exportExcel";

$.ajax({
    url: urlAjaxExportExcel,
    type: "post",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

La parte del controlador:

```
public function exportExcel()
{
    session_start();
    $comedorE = $_SESSION['com_caja'];
    $fechaE = date('Y-m-d');

    $dataExport = $this -> model -> selectVentas($comedorE, $fechaE);

    if (empty($dataExport)) {
        $arrResponse = array('status' => false, 'msg' => 'No hay datos para exportar.');
    } else {
        $filename = "cierre_venta_" . $fechaE . ".xls";
        $salida = "";
        $salida .= "<table>";
        $salida .= "<thead><th>Codigo</th><th>Comedor</th><th>Fecha</th><th>Entrada</th><th>Fondo</th><th>Postre</th><th>Total</th><th>Estado</th></thead>";

        foreach ($dataExport as $dex) {
            $salida .= "<tr><td>" . $dex["codigo"] . "</td><td>" . $dex["comedor"] . "</td><td>" . $dex["fecha"] . "</td><td>" . $dex["entrada"] . "</td><td>" . $dex["fondo"] . "</td><td>" . $dex["postre"] . "</td><td>" . $dex["total"] . "</td><td>" . $dex["estado"] . "</td></tr>";
        }

        $salida .= "</table>";

        header("Content-Type:application/xls");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");

        echo $salida;
    }
}
```

Se supone que con ese echo $salida, debería exportar, pero como viene del jQuery en el console.log(response) se muestra todo lo que está en la variable $salida, pero nada del archivo Excel.

Alguien que me pudiera dar una guía por favor.

Gracias,

---

Hice este cambio en la petición Ajax:

```
var urlAjaxExportExcel = base_url + "Ventas/exportExcel";

$.ajax({
    url: urlAjaxExportExcel,
    type: "post",
    cache: false,
    xhrFields: {
        responseType: 'blob'
    },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Y me devuelve esto el console.log:

```
Blob { size: 1217, type: "application/xls" }
```

Hay algo que me esté faltando por hacer?

Comment: Para poder recibir la respuesta de la peticion como archivo, debes especificarle a ajax que es un archivo. [Esta respuesta tal vez te sirva](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/514472/exportar-archivo-excel-con-ajax-php-y-javascript)

Comment: Hola, ya lo solucioné, el archivo excel descarga, pero lo hace en la carpeta de descargas, como se podría hacer para que descargue en una dirección específica, por ejemplo en el disco duro C:\

    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(response);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = "cierre.xls";
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

Comment: No se si se entiende la parte del código, no se como podría darle formato al código desde los comentario.

Comment: Puedes responder tu propia pregunta, para que las personas que tengan el mismo problema tengan indicios de como solucionarlos.

Comment: No tiene sentido querer hacer que el archivo se descargue en una carpeta específica, pues puede que algunos clientes ni siquiera tengan dicha carpeta, porque se llama de otro modo, o porque está accediendo desde un dispositivo que tiene otro sistema de archivos (Mac, Linux, dispositivos móviles, etc).